# Make smaller image cover bigger div and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, image

I have a user uploaded image inside of a div with a fixed width and height. The image inside is aligned to the center vertically. Works fine.

The problem is that sometimes, the height of the image is smaller than the height of the div.

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uq03m5go/) for example.

How do I make the image always fit the height of the div **and maintain its aspect ratio**?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="b_feat_img">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iEJWyXN.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="b_feat_img">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qRkEJni.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width:120px;
}

.b_feat_img {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background:red;
    float: left;
    height: 96px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.b_feat_img img {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0px, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I will bounty this question with 50 points when it's eligible.

Comment: You didn't mention the width of image, I assumed that you want it to cover the div and allow cutting off edges.

Comment: @Pangloss Yes, that's correct. As long as it covers the height of the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In supported browsers*. You can use **[`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)** with value of **`cover`**, it works similarly to `background-size:cover`, but for inline images.

```
.b_feat_img img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 120px;
}
.b_feat_img {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  height: 96px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
.b_feat_img img {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="b_feat_img">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/iEJWyXN.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="b_feat_img">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/qRkEJni.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

`*` Note, at the time of writing, IE doesn't support it, be sure to see the [support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).